# Error when two same json object in the same PHP file

Tags: php, mysql, json

Currently I want just want to test using two JSON objects in same PHP files. I do this test because my current project used two JSON objects. When I do the test, an error occurred which are

1) Undefined property stdClass:: $bookingList on line 19

3) Trying to get property 'endTime' on line 21

and below is my code

test.php

```
<?php

$Book_No = 1;

$url4 = "http://172.20.0.45/TGWebService/TGWebService.asmx/displayBookingData?timeStart=&timeEnd=&Room_ID=&Book_No=$Book_No";
$data4 = file_get_contents($url4);
$json4 = json_decode($data4);
$results = $json4->bookingList;

$StartTime4 = $results[0]->startTime;
$EndTime4 = $results[0]->endTime;
$Room_ID4 = $results[0]->roomID;
$Book_No4 = $results[0]->bookNo;


$url3 = "http://172.20.0.45/TGWebService/TGWebService.asmx/displayBookingData?timeStart=". urlencode($StartTime4) . "&timeEnd=" . urlencode($EndTime4). "&Room_ID=$Room_ID4&Book_No=$Book_No4";
$data3 = file_get_contents($url3);
$json3 = json_decode($data3);
$results10 = $json3->bookingList; //line 19

$End = $results10->endTime; //line 21

echo $End;

?>
```

Why does this error happen? Can anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Could you post the `print_r()` or `var_dump()` on these json results? In this way, one could see possibly if simply what you want to fetch in the json is even there.

Comment: @GetSet Im new in json programming. Can I know where to put var_dump?

Comment: After `$json4 = json_decode($data4);` put `var_dump($json4);` And follow the same pattern for `$json3`. ..... Then look at those results to see if you see `bookingList` and `endTime`.

Comment: @GetSet i get tje error: trying to get 'endTime' line 21

Comment: Put `error_reporting(0);` at the top of the script to supress the errors. Or simply comment out the offending lines. What you need to do is check the var_dump's results to look for the bookingList and endTime

Comment: object(stdClass)#1 (5) { ["statusCode"]=> string(1) "1" ["errCode"]=> string(0) "" ["title"]=> string(25) "Booking within range List" ["desc"]=> string(0) "" ["bookingList"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#2 (12) { ["bookNo"]=> string(1) "1" ["bookDate"]=> string(19) "2020-01-30 00:00:00"..........

Comment: @GetSet result like above

Comment: After `$json3 = json_decode($data3);` put `var_dump($json3);` also. And post both var_dump() results to your original question, not in this comments section. Include the whole output, don't excerpt it with dots.